# Making div clickable for the link inside the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a div clickable for the link that is contained in that div. I cannot use onclick function since that link is created dynamically. It is a wordpress website.

I tried this method,

```
$(".pt-cv-ifield").click(function(){
 window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
});
```

I created this jquery and saved this as clickable.js, and added it to functions.php in my theme file.

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'clickable', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/clickable.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

Not working. Jquery is a working solution anymore. So past answers are no good.

Comment: Not sure why you are not using onclick, but you can achieve what you want with an anchor tag inside that div

Comment: @vladc imho using onclick is a little outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the element is created after the page is loaded.
add the event to document instead of the element itself like this:
You also need to set `window.location.href` instead of just `window.location`.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".pt-cv-ifield", function(){
 window.location.href = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
});
```

It could be you need to use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` in Wordpress.